# Configure android EditText to allow decimals and negatives

Tags: android, android-edittext, decimal

I have an Android `EditText` that I want to have the number keyboard come up.

If I set the android:inputType to numberSigned, I get the number keyboard and the ability to type in negatives.  However this won't let me use decimals.  If I use the numberDecimal inputType I can use decimals but not negatives.

How do you get the number keyboard with the ability to type in decimals and negatives?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You are just missing this in your EditText,

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

Comment: Even though this has the highest vote as at now, it still doesn't work for me. hrrh

Answer (score 17):

We can use,

```
edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

if we need to use programmatically..

Answer (score 7):

See this link may be it's help you
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html

and The possible values for the android:inputtype are:

```
•none
•text
•textCapCharacters
•textCapWords
•textCapSentences
•textAutoCorrect
•textAutoComplete
•textMultiLine
•textImeMultiLine
•textNoSuggestions
•textUri
•textEmailAddress
•textEmailSubject
•textShortMessage
•textLongMessage
•textPersonName
•textPostalAddress
•textPassword
•textVisiblePassword
•textWebEditText
•textFilter
•textPhonetic
•textWebEmailAddress
•textWebPassword
•number
•numberSigned
•numberDecimal
•numberPassword
•phone
•datetime
•date
•time
```

Answer (score 3):

Some phones have the decimal and negative in the same button and makes it unable to do negatives. I figured out a way you could separate the buttons by simply adding-

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned|textPersonName"
```

android:digits="0123456789-."

That way you still have the number keyboard layout but the negative and decimal buttons will be separate and you cannot use any other digit that messes up the app.

Answer (score 2):

Tested, solution is

```
inputET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Comment: This works fine in Zebra devices

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me programmatically.Below is the code :

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```